# How to set (or get) the name when creating an ElastiCache ParameterGroup via CDK?

Tags: aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk, amazon-elasticache

When a Parameter Group is created via AWS Console, there is a Name field, and the [`CreateCacheParameterGroup`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/APIReference/API_CreateCacheParameterGroup.html) API action has a `CacheParameterGroupName` parameter.

However, there does not seem to be a way of setting the name with [CloudFormation/CDK](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-elasticache-parameter-group.html).

Without setting the name, the Parameter Group is created with a generated name. But there [does not seem to be a way of getting the name](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_elasticache.CfnParameterGroup.html) either. So, how can a `ReplicationGroup` reference the `ParameterGroup` when both are deployed in the same stack?

```js
const parameterGroup = new elasticache.CfnParameterGroup(this, 'ParameterGroup', {...});

const redis = new elasticache.CfnReplicationGroup(this, 'ReplicationGroup', {
  ...
  cacheParameterGroupName: // What should go here???
  ...
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`parameterGroup.ref` will resolve to the string `cacheParameterGroupName` is looking for.

`CfnElement.ref`:  "Return a string that will be resolved to a CloudFormation `{ Ref }` for this element"

N.B. The draft L2 [ParameterGroup](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/blob/7cec4dce04099ff81eacffa01c3316a244e5e786/packages/%40aws-cdk/aws-elasticache/lib/parameter-group.ts#L106) Construct implements its name property in this way.